# Starting Kafka Server Permanently

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I have setup Kafka on Amazon EC2 instance.

I have done the following in below order:
(1) SSH into the Instance
(2) Start Zookeper
(3) Start Kafka
(4) Execute Producer and Consumer Programs.

Everything is working fine till here. However once I close the SSH window on which I have started Kafka, the Kafka service stops. I can no longer execute Producer and Consumer programs.

How can I have the Kafka Server permanently up for all requests, even after I close the SSH window.

Thank You.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`nohup` is required at the beginning of command, so that output is not on screen, but in file. Also `&` is required at the end of command to start the server in background:

> bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
>
> bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

will change to:

> nohup bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties &
>
> nohup bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &

Comment: Using `-daemon` switch is the better option now

Comment: @kopos would you elaborate why that is the case?

Comment: @RichardSteinbrecht `nohup .. &` is technically doing what `-daemon` supports already. To run the kafka server headless as a daemon

Answer (score 53):

This is now officially supported in kafka and zookeeper startup scripts. So if you are on latest (Since Aug 2015) kafka you can use -daemon as follows.

```
# ./kafka-server-start.sh
USAGE: ./kafka-server-start.sh [-daemon] server.properties

# ./zookeeper-server-start.sh
USAGE: ./zookeeper-server-start.sh [-daemon] zookeeper.properties
```

Comment: @NikeshDevaki, -daemon is what you should use now since that's supported by kafka directly.

Comment: This does not work on Windows (starting ZK, Kafka using `.bat` files)

Comment: Is there a way to get the logs to be displayed as it initializes? It seems like the `-daemon` flag hides all of those so it becomes harder to troubleshoot potential startup exceptions.

Answer (score 37):

Try `bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties.`

OR:

Try upstart script here:[upstart script for kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053111/upstart-script-for-kafka)

Comment: no idea why so few people upvoted my answer, but the following one.... No much difference

Comment: after executing above shell, how to check if it already running?

Comment: how to stop zookeeper and Kafka if it's unnecessary ?